# How can I go about recording a video of a Sprite in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, red5, flash-media-server, video-recording

I have a web-based AS3 application that opens a webcam and overlays some animations.

I'm taking the camera as a Bitmap and rendering it to a Sprite (myAwesomeSprite). The animation is added as a child of myAwesomeSprite. I can take still images of myAwesomeSprite and save them via JPGEncode().

I would like to record myAwesomeSprite as a video, capturing the webcam and animation together. I understand I would need access to a Flash Media Server or Red5 Server to do this.

All the references I've seen to recording and saving Flash video refer to recording the camera only, not the camera + other elements. It's not entirely clear to me i can record camera+animation.

If I have a Sprite myAwesomeSprite, how can I record it as video and save it to a server?

Answer (score 1):

You could upload all your JPEGs to the server and have it run a tool to convert them to a movie. However this is too slow.

A different option is to convert a tool like ffmpeg to AS3 using Adobe Alchemy. Ralph Hauwert from Aviary has done this. Aviary Peacook can create videos but I guess it was a very complex task to get ffmpeg through Alchemy.

However in that solution everything is done on the client-side which is what you want to do.